# Populating a div with JSON data from Google API with auto refresh, on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

*tl;dr: Want to have an HTML page with a div that refreshes every ten minutes and pulls trip time data from Google Maps Distance Matrix API.*

I've got a wallboard running off a Raspberry Pi, displaying a custom HTML page which displays two sections (divs) - the top is a calendar that links to Dakboard, and the bottom I'm trying to display transit time to a series of destinations using the Google Maps Distance Matrix API. I have my URL with origin and destination, and everything works to return me JSON data, but I don't know what to *do* with it. I have no experience with dynamic HTML pages, but it really looks pretty similar to C++, which I majored in many many years ago so I have some recollection of.

My goal is to have the bottom div on my page refresh every ten minutes, pulling data from the Distance Matrix API to tell me how long it will take to reach a list of destinations, without refreshing the top div. My thought is that I need to write some script which calls out to the Google URL and stores that data in an array which the HTML file then uses to display readable text. Two minutes of Google says I'll need to use AJAX to refresh only that div, though I also know nothing about AJAX.

**Sample URL to pull data (API key removed):**
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=sacramento+ca&destinations=santa+cruz+ca|san+francisco+ca&key=*MY_API_KEY*

**Sample results:**
{ "destination_addresses" : [ "Santa Cruz, CA, USA", "San Francisco, CA, USA" ], "origin_addresses" : [ "Sacramento, CA, USA" ], "rows" : [ { "elements" : [ { "distance" : { "text" : "147 mi", "value" : 236412 }, "duration" : { "text" : "2 hours 26 mins", "value" : 8778 }, "status" : "OK" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "87.2 mi", "value" : 140327 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 hour 31 mins", "value" : 5443 }, "status" : "OK" } ] } ], "status" : "OK" }

**Desired output on webpage based on above results:**
Sacramento to Santa Cruz: 2 hours 26 minutes
Sacramento to San Francisco: 1 hour 31 minutes

Willing to learn, just not sure where to start. Help is appreciated!